# How to find the closed form solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the sequence 5,11,18,26,35,45....

Can someone show me how to do the closed form solution step by step. The recursive solution is H(n - 1) + 4 +n If I'm not wrong.

Comment: What is $H$ ???

Comment: n = 1, 2,3 4,5 ...

Comment: H(n) = 5,11,18,26,35,45

Comment: I think it is one of those questions in sequences, where a sequence is given and then one needs to find a rule governs the sequence and proves it.  Perhaps https://oeis.org/A056000.

Comment: would the closed form solution be a(n) = n*(n+9)/2.?

Comment: What is $a(n)$ ?

Comment: I copied it from the website that Salech send me. In my case it would be H(n)

Comment: See [Recursive definition: Finding closed forms](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs173/fa2011/Lectures/recursive-definition.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are right and the sequence is defined by the recurrence:

$\begin{align*}
  H(n)
     &= H(n - 1) + n + 4 \\
  H(1)
     &= 5
\end{align*}$

(values inferred from the sequence's first two), you can just:

$\begin{align*}
  H(n) - H(n - 1)
     &= n + 4 \\
  \sum_{2 \le k \le n} (H(k) - H(k - 1))
     &= \sum_{2 \le k \le n} (n + 4) \\
  H(n) - H(1)
     &= \frac{n (n + 1)}{2} - 1 + 4 (n - 1) \\
 H(n)
    &= \frac{n (n + 9)}{2}
\end{align*}$

All I used is the sum of the first $n$ numbers.

Comment: Thank you. This made things more clearer for me!

Answer (score 1):

The first order differences are $6,7,8,9,10\cdots$, hence linear ($n+5$). The sequence will follow a quadratic law, which we can find by Lagrangian interpolation or by indeterminate coefficients.

As the first order difference of $n^2$ is $2n + 1$, we already know that the leading term is $\dfrac{n^2}2$.

Hence

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{1^2}2+a\cdot1+b=5,\\\dfrac{2^2}2+a\cdot2+b=11.\end{cases}$$

By subtraction, $a=\dfrac92$, then $b=0$.

$$\frac{n^2+9n}2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using some very basic ideas from the "calculus of finite differences." We define, for a function $f$, $$\Delta f(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$$. Note that for your function $$f(n+1)=f(n)+n+5,\text {so} \Delta f(n)=n+5$$ and $f(1)=5.$ We also need the 'factorial powers' symbolism:
 $$n^{(0)}=n^0=1.n^{(1)}=n^1=1,n^{(i)}=n(n-1)...(n-i+1) \text{ for }i \ge 2$$ and the results $$\Delta n^{(i)}=in^{(i-1)} \text{ and }n^{(i)}=\Delta(\frac{n^{(i+1)}}{i+1}).$$ Note that $\Delta$ is a linear operator and that $\Delta(constant)=0.$Thus for your function $$\Delta f(n)=n+5=n^{(1)}+5n^{(0)}$$ $$=\Delta(\frac{n^{(2)}}{2}+5n^{(1)})$$ $$=\Delta(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+5n)$$ $$=\Delta(\frac{n^2+9n}{2})$$
$$f(n)=\frac{n^2+9n}{2}+K$$ Since $ f(1)=5, K=0.$
$$f(n)=\frac{n^2+9n}{2}.$$